# Redirect after google form submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to redirect users off the google form submission confirmation page. I use google forms as a log and there are dozens of submissions every day by 100's of people. I have an issue where users will keep the internet tabs open for days, and they will get one to refresh, resubmitting an old log entry. This causes big issues with the scripts that I have to populate fields, based off the last submission.

Is there anyway I can direct them to another page for the confirmation, so that I don't get re submissions from them later on?

Comment: It's not possible to change the confirmation page, but the main issue is users not closing the tab for days (?). You could customize the Confirmation message to remind them to close the page.

Comment: Yeah, I already have that. I deal with a lot of people that don't like to listen...